# ReactJS CKEditor OnReady event not firing

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

Attempting to implement CKEditor 5 in a new ReactJS component and I cannot get the reference to the editor.  As it turns out, the `onReady` event is not firing:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';


export const Editor = () => {
    const [editorData,setEditorData] = useState();
    const editorRef = useRef();

    const handleEditorOnReady = (editor) => {
        console.log("Event should fire!!!")
        editorRef.current = editor;
    };

    return(
        <div id="editor">
            <CKEditor
                editor={ClassicEditor}
                data={editorData}
                onReady={handleEditorOnReady}
                onChange={(e, editor) => { setEditorData(editor.getData()) }}
            />      
        </div>
    )
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this?  Thank you!

Comment: Which version of ckeditor5 and ckeditor5-react are you using?